# What is the best way to run a query for this situation?

Tags: mysql, spreadsheet

I have a situation where I must basically populate a spreadsheet with my information from a database. This site involves runners and the time it takes them to finish a race.  On my vertical column, it lists the names of the runners and on the horizontal going across, it lists the races. It is simple enough to get the data and output for one race, but the problem I have is in regards to doing this  for multiple races and presenting it in a spreadsheet like format.

My tables are in the following way:

```
    runner   race number   time
    ----------------------------
    jack     1             2 hours
    jack     2             2.5 hours
    mike     1             1 hour
    mike     2             1.5 hours
    shelly   1             2.5 hours
    shelly   2             3 hours
```

and I want to present in on my site in the following way

```
    Runner    Race Number 1    Race Number 2
    -----------------------------------------
    Jack        2 hours            2.5 hours      
    Mike        1 hour             1.5 hours
    Shelly      2.5 hours          3 hours
```

At first I thought to just run multiple queries, one query for every race, but since I must present it in a table like the second one above, it becomes a bit more tricky.

Comment: Please post an example of your database tables and the expected format

Answer (score 0):

You have to join 2 derived tables like this:

```
SELECT r1.name AS runner, 
race_number1 AS "Race Number 1", 
race_number2  AS "Race Number 2"
FROM 
(SELECT name, time AS race_number1 FROM races WHERE race_number=1) r1 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT name, time AS race_number2 FROM races WHERE race_number=2) r2
ON r1.name=r2.name
```

Here's a [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c296fc/3)

The most important thing you should be doing is setting name as `UNIQUE`, or if not you should have a table runners with a unique id for each runner...